# Get Data ArrayObject inside array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
MONTHLY_PAYMENT: "9.7",
MAINTAINANCE_FEE: "20000",
areapoints: [
{
station: "大塚",
bus: null,
walking_distance: null
},
{
station: null,
bus: null,
walking_distance: null
},
{
station: null,
bus: null,
walking_distance: null
}
]
```

Getting the monthly payment and maintenance fee is easy, I just use `$room->MONTHLY_PAYMENT`.

But there is an arrayobject inside of the array which I am getting an error when I use  `$room->areapoints[0]->bus`

This is the error:

```
Undefined property: ArrayObject::$bus
```

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$room->areapoints[0]->bus` to `$room->areapoints[0]['bus']`

Answer (score 1):

Your property of `$room->areapoints[0]->bus` is `null` in your list syntax. Therefore, that property doesn't exist.

You need to check if it exists before using it with:

```
if (isset($room->areapoints[0]->bus)) {
    // ... CODE HERE ...
}
```

Comment: My question is how to get the data inside, not how to handle nulls, but thanks anyway